# The relationship between the negative binomial distribution and poisson distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics

How can I get the poisson distribution from the negative binomial distribution?

Comment: did you have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Related_distributions

Comment: yes, actually i need the process of proof.

Comment: Don't paste your homework here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let lambda = n(1-p) and have n approach infinity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationships_among_probability_distributions[image]

Comment: Thanks. it's really difficult to memorize all these relationships.